# Calling Fortran subroutine from C++ OpenMP parallel for should work?

Tags: c++, multithreading, fortran, openmp, mixed-programming

When calling a Fortran subroutine from a C++ function, and the C++ function is called inside an OpenMP parallel for construct, the Fortran subroutine returns different values from time to time. It is a blackbox subroutine that should return the same result with the same input (50 arguments). I parallelized the subroutine call in order to run it for hundreds of different input combinations. If I run the program twice and print the results from each subroutine execution, the results are not the same.

Details about the problem :

1. The serial version is consistent and working fine, giving the same answer all the time;
2. The subroutine does not use pseudo random generated numbers;
3. The subroutine calls other subroutines in the same .F90 file;
4. There is no nesting and no openmp pragmas or includes inside fortran subroutines;
5. If I try to use OpenMP API functions inside Fortran subroutines they return gibberish;
6. I am using -fautomatic, -fopenmp and -frecursive when compiling with gfortran (btw I am using gcc 5.2.0) and all subroutines were made RECURSIVE. Everything is compiling and linking fine and the problem does appear when I run the .exe.
7. The Fortran subroutines do not access I/O. All variables are passed through arguments. There are no COMMON or SAVED blocks. All subroutines use dummy arguments and output variables are explicitly initialized inside every subroutine;
8. I am not using any OpenMP clauses with #pragma omp parallel for.
9. The number of discrepancies between results is reduced if the number of threads is smaller than the number of available processors. Binding threads with processors does not solve the problem.

The code is huge, but I have managed to simplify it in an example to illustrate the problem :

```
//StdAfx.h
#include "other.h"
#include <omp.h>
//...many other includes 

//first.cpp
#include "StdAfx.h"
typedef struct
{
    float x[51];
    float result;
} A;
typedef A *B;
B old=NULL;
int size;
float weight;
int var;

int main()
{
    size = 100;
    old = new (nothrow) A[size];
    long* control=NULL;
    control = new long[size];
    int kk;
    //...
    //changing some control[] values to -1
    var = 5; weight = 0.7;
    //...
    #pragma omp parallel for
    for (kk=0; kk<=size-1; kk++)
    {
        if (control[kk]>-1) old[kk].result = calcresult(old[kk].x,kk);
    }
    ...
    delete [] old;
    oldpop = NULL;
    delete [] control;
    control = NULL;
}
float calcresult(float *x, int k)
{
    int dev=0;
    double kresult;
    dev = 10;
    kresult = othercalcresult(&x[0],k);
    kresult += (weight*dev*double(1.0/var));
    return(kresult);
}

//other.h
float othercalcresult(float *x, int anyk=0);

//other.cpp
extern "C" {
void _stdcall fdlf_(int VET[93],int *N, double *extresult);
}
double anothercalcresult(float *x, int *iVet)
{
    int iN=1;
    double extresult=0.0;
    //stuff here
    //original fortran subroutine has 50 arguments
    fdlf_(iVet,&iN,&extresult);
    return(extresult);
}
float othercalcresult(float *x, int anyk=0)
{
    unsigned int i,ii;
    float otherresult=0.0;
    int ulimit;
    //ulimit = 10;
    //iVet is a two dimensional array iVet
    int** iVet = new int*[numcenarios_anaprog_local];
    for (ii=0; ii<ulimit; ii++) iVet[ii]=new int[93];
    //initialize new vector
    for (i=0; i<ulimit; i++) 
        for (ii=0; ii<93; ii++) 
            iVet[i][ii]=(100*i)+ii;
    double* partialresult=NULL;
    partialresult= new double[ulimit];
    for (int jj=0;jj<ulimit;jj++) partialresult[jj] = 0.0;
    //stuff here
    for (i=0;i<ulimit;i++) partialresult[i] = anothercalcresult(x,iVet[i])
    for (i=0;i<ulimit;i++) otherresult+=float(partialresult[i]);
    return(otherresult);
}

//EXT.F90
RECURSIVE SUBROUTINE AUXSUB1(N,VALUE1)
    INTEGER N
    REAL*8 VALUE1
    VALUE1 = 1 / (2 ** N)
    RETURN
END SUBROUTINE AUXSUB1

RECURSIVE SUBROUTINE AUXSUB2(N,VALUE2)
    INTEGER N
    REAL*8 VALUE2
    VALUE2 = 1 / (3 ** N)
    RETURN
END SUBROUTINE AUXSUB2

RECURSIVE SUBROUTINE FDLF(VET,N,EXTRESULT)
    INTEGER VET(93),N
    REAL*8 VALUE1, VALUE2, EXTRESULT
    VALUE1 = 0.
    VALUE2 = 0.
    EXTRESULT = 0.0
    CALL AUXSUB1(N,VALUE1)
    CALL AUXSUB2(N,VALUE2)
    DO I=1,93
        IF I.LT.47 THEN 
            EXTRESULT = EXTRESULT + VALUE1
        ELSE
            EXTRESULT = EXTRESULT + VALUE2
        END IF
    END DO
    EXTRESULT = 1 / EXTRESULT
    RETURN
END SUBROUTINE FDLF
```

Comment: Right now, your declaration of `fdlf_` only has two variables whereas you give it 3 and it wants 3. Is this a typo here and are you sure all 50 variables in your original code are sent properly/declared properly?

Comment: @NoseKnowsAll It was a typo...Tks..It is ok now. If they work in serial version, do you think that should be a problem?

Comment: @HighPerformanceMark Another typo...sorry again. The code was inherited from others and made in the 1990's. In the sample, I was trying to bring its characteristics for our discussion here. Including the bad and horrible ones... Do you think it will interfere with OpenMP ?

Comment: @HighPerformanceMark And about the recursive, it was included to make all local variables automatic. I was trying (and overkilling) everything.

Comment: @HighPerformanceMark Typo again. Rewriting everything is always an option. I don't like the code either. Tks for your opinion. However, none was said about parallel vs. serial. How does it interfere with the problem at hand? Btw, I have already included implicit none and explicitly declared all variables in the original code and the problem is still there.